# iOS6 Camera Overlay Does Not Allow Editing

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, ios6

In my app, I need to have a Camera Overlay to help the user line up the picture correctly for it's intended use.  Further, I need to have the Editing interface to let them fine tune the zoom and alignment with this "guide". I have gotten the Camera overlay to work with the default Camera Controls (the editing pane won't even show unless you use the default controls) , however now on the editing screen, I cannot zoom/pan.  The touch events seem to occur on the overlay, and not the editing screen.  I know/knew this was a potential problem, and have implemented the fix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178214/cameraoverlayview-prevents-editing-with-allowsediting/10300147#10300147)

This allows focusing on the camera screen itself, you can see the touches are being passed through/ignored in the overlay, but on the editing screen this is still not working.  I have also tried some of the hittest code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719412/how-to-ignore-touch-events-and-pass-them-to-another-subviews-uicontrol-objects)

That solution gives me an error every time that  No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'hitTest:withEvent:' on the super line.

I have also tried all kinds of settings playing with the userInteractionEnabled property

Here is the code I am using to do the overlay:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
self.picker.allowsEditing = YES;
self.picker.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

// Insert the overlay
self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverlayViewController" bundle:nil];
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;

self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
[self.picker.cameraOverlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
//[self.picker.cameraOverlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;
```

// [self performSelector:@selector(moveOverlayViewToSublayer:) withObject:self.picker afterDelay:0.1f];

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting a custom overlay working using a xib file and ended up just creating the  overlay view in code.

There are examples of how to achieve this around the Net:

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196